# Access to debug (profiler) information before redirection in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

After submitting a form I usually redirect a user to another page (other than the form itself).

Therefore I lose the Profile (debug information, like log). I mean after clicking the Debug Toolbar I get information about the request after redirection. But I do know Symfony keeps information about the previous page. I mean it doesn't forget it. Is there a way to access this information? Where is the debug info about the request before redirection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the Profiler, there is a menu on the left and content area on the right.  At the top of that right content area you will see `View Last 10` or `View All`, where you can click to open up previous requests.

From there, simply click on the request that submitted the form, which will be the most recent `POST` request that you see.

Comment: Wow, that was fast:) Thank you!

Comment: Thanks hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

In `config_dev.yml` you can change that behaviour setting `intercept_redirects` to **true**

```
web_profiler:
    intercept_redirects: true
```